# Как получить доступ к элементам

Tags: jquery, json, массивы

Есть строка json

```
var str='{"name1":"1","name2":"2","name3":["1","2","3"]}';
data = $.parseJSON(str);
alert(data.name3.....?); //??
```

Как получить доступ к внутреннему не ассоциативному массиву?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.name3` здесь массив,  и так уже. странный вопрос.

```
var str='{"name1":"1","name2":"2","name3":["1","2","3"]}';
var data = $.parseJSON(str);
alert(data.name3[0]); //!!! 1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ZAayj/

Comment: Вот именно, что массив, а у меня ошибку выдает такую

    name3 is not defiend

Comment: а где выдает (в примере же все работает), очевидно что str у вас не такой, какой вы показываете. сделайте console.log(data) и раскройте  объект в дебагере.

Comment: у меня data вот такой: 

    Object 
      name1: "1"
      name2: "2"
      name3: Array[3]
        0: "1"
        1: "2"
        2: "3"
        length: 3

Comment: У меня такой же, однако ругается при обращении на массив

Comment: в fiddle тоже ? какой браузер ?

Comment: Все, мой косяк, оказывается и вправду такого массива не было, то есть массив пустой при первом обращении, а во второй раз срабатывает, когда я заношу данные в обект